# Algorithm for getting the Age and the leap years since birth

Tags: php, date, date-difference

calculate the total number of leap years IN DAYS since his or her birthyear.

sample input from user: 1993
and the output should be : 2562

update:

here's my code so far, i created an algorithm if the specific year is a leap year.

```
if($yr%4 == 0) {

 $leaps++;

}
```

thinking about making a loop starting from 1993 and check every year if its a leap year.

**update2** : **solved**. here's what I did. thanks guys

```
<?php 

    $dt = date("Y");

    $nm = $_POST['name'];
    $yr = $_POST['year'];
    $leaps = 0;
    $total = 0;
    $age = $dt - $yr;

    for($i = $yr; $i < $dt ; $i++) {

        if($i %4 == 0) {

            $leaps++;

        }

        $total = 366 * $leaps;
    }

    echo "Hi $nm, you are $age years old. There were $total since your birthday";
```

?>

Comment: What you have tried so far ? Please post your code.

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong for calculating leap years in Gregorian calendar. See algorithm [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm) >>> `if year is not divisible by 4 then common year /
else if year is not divisible by 100 then leap year /
else if year is divisible by 400 then leap year /
else common year`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is what you are looking for:

```
<?php

     $now = time(); // or your date as well
     $your_date = strtotime("1993-01-01");
     $datediff = $now - $your_date;
     echo floor($datediff/(60*60*24));

?>
```